# Get the standard deviation of a row ignoring the min and max values

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following data frame:

| a | b | c | d | e | sd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -100 | 2 | 3 | 60 | 4 | 1 |
| 7 | 5 | -50 | 9 | 130 | 2 |

How would I calculate the standard deviation `sd` column which excludes the minimum and maximum values from each row?

The actual data frame is a few million rows long so something vectorised would be great!

To replicate:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"a": [-100, 7], "b": [2, 5], "c": [3, -50], "d": [60, 9], "e": [4, 130]}
)
```

Comment: What if there are multiple occurrences of the min/max values in a given row?

Comment: Please clarify what should happen if you have several min/max (e.g. if the `2` is a `-100` in the first row).

Comment: I'd not thought about this but as the actual data frame will contain very granular floats then it's extremely unlikely that there will be dupes so I'd go for the fastest solution. @mozway - looks like you provided an answer for both variants so thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### Excluding the first min/max

An approach that should be fast would be to use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) to [`sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) the values per row, exclude the first and last and compute the [`std`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html):

```
df['sd'] = np.sort(df, axis=1)[:, 1:-1].std(axis=1, ddof=1)
```

##### Handling duplicate min/max (excluding all)

If you can have several times the same min/max and want to exclude all, then you could compute a mask:

```
m1 = df.ne(df.min(axis=1), axis=0)
m2 = df.ne(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)

df['sd'] = df.where(m1&m2).std(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     a  b   c   d    e   sd
0 -100  2   3  60    4  1.0
1    7  5 -50   9  130  2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

To go further and in addition to @mozway's answer, what happens if you have values close to min (-95) or max (58)? Your variance will also be irrelevant due to outliers. Another approach consists to remove outliers using IQR:

```
q = df.quantile([0.25, 0.75], axis=1).T
q1, q3 = q[0.25], q[0.75]
iqr = q3 - q1
lb, ub = q1 - 1.5 * iqr, q3 + 1.5 * iqr

df['sd'] = df.where(df.ge(lb, axis=0) & df.le(ub, axis=0)).std(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     a  b   c   d    e   sd
0 -100  2   3  60    4  1.0
1    7  5 -50   9  130  2.0

>>> q
   0.25  0.75
0   2.0   4.0
1   5.0   9.0

>>> lb  # keep only values greater or equals to lower bound
0   -1.0
1   -1.0
dtype: float64

>>> ub  # keep only values lower or equals to upper bound
0     7.0
1    15.0
dtype: float64

>>> df.where(df.ge(lb, axis=0) & df.le(ub, axis=0))
     a  b    c    d    e
0  NaN  2  3.0  NaN  4.0
1  7.0  5  NaN  9.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"a": [-100, 7], "b": [2, 5], "c": [3, -50], "d": [60, 9], "e": [4, 130]}
)

# Calculate standard deviation excluding min and max
df['sd'] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(row).sort_values().iloc[1:-1].std(), axis=1)

print(df)



    a   b   c   d    e   sd
0 -100  2   3  60    4  1.0
1    7  5 -50   9  130  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension

```
df['std'] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series([x for x in row if x not in [row.min(), row.max()]]).std(), axis=1)


     a  b   c   d    e  std
0 -100  2   3  60    4  1.0
1    7  5 -50   9  130  2.0
```